# css: button group layout: reflow into pairs when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, button, layout

I'd like to make three rows of fixed-sized buttons; four buttons in the top and bottom rows, and two in the middle row.
The rows with four buttons should resize in two rows of *two* buttons when the browser window gets too narrow. There must never be three button in a row (I'm OK with one button per row if the browser is too narrow). Ideally, the row with the two button will be centred. Something likes that (each  triplet representing a button):

```
B1B B2B B3B B4B
    CCC CCC
D1D D2D D3D D4D
```

when resized ('|' denotes right-hand browser edge - there is sufficient room for three but not four buttons, so I want it to resize to two buttons per row):

```
B1B B2B    |
B3B B4B    |
CCC CCC    |
D1D D2D    |
D3D D4D    |
```

I'm truly flummoxed how to do this. 
flex containers make the desired layout but I cannot prevent re-sizing to three buttons if there is sufficient space. Lists (with hidden cells at the left and right of the middle row) don't float left when the browser becomes three buttons wide.
This needs to work in a site that only allows HTML and CSS (no scripts or externals like bootstrap).
Is this possible at all? All tips appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us your code? Or even better, create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) ot [bin](http://jsbin.com/) so we could help you.

Comment: This is my current best-attempt (far from what I hope to achieve). I have not included the failed attempts using lists. Thans for the 'bin' tip! I hope I'm sharing this correctly: [bin](http://jsbin.com/jasoroh/edit?html,output). Many thanks for your help!